# How would you hide an edit and delete button for something the user doesn't own

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I only want the signed in user to see the edit and delete button for the playlists they created.

```
playListsCreated.js (this is the file that displays the created playlists)

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import messages from '../AutoDismissAlert/messages'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

import { playListIndex, playListDelete } from '../../api/playList'

import './playList.scss'

class PlayListsCreated extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      playlists: [],
      playlist: {
        title: ''
      },
      userEqualsOwner: true
    }
  }

  handleChange = event => this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  })
  componentDidMount () {
    const { user } = this.props
    playListIndex(user)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ playlists: res.data.playlists })
      })
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.persist()

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedField = {
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      }
      const updatedData = Object.assign({}, prevState.playlist, updatedField)
      return { playlist: updatedData }
    })
  }

  onPlaylistDelete = (event, id) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    playListDelete(this.props.user, id)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ text: '' })
        this.props.msgAlert({
          heading: 'Playlist Deleted!',
          message: messages.deletePlaylistSuccess,
          variant: 'success'
        })
      })
      .then(props => {
        playListIndex(this.props.user)
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({ playlists: res.data.playlists })
          })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.props.msgAlert({
          heading: 'Playlist delete failed ' + error.message,
          message: messages.deletePlaylistFailure,
          variant: 'danger'
        })
      })
  }

  handlePlaylistUpdate = (event) => {
    event.persist()

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const uField = {
        'text': event.target.value
      }
      const uData = Object.assign({}, prevState.playlist, uField)
      return { title: uData }
    })
  }

  render () {
    const playlists = this.state.playlists.map(playlist => (
      <li key={playlist._id}>
        <Link to={`/playListUpdate/${playlist._id}`}>{playlist.title}</Link>
        {(this.props.user._id === playlist.owner) ? (
          <div>
            <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.onPlaylistDelete} className="btn btn-secondary deleteButton">Delete</Button>{' '}
            <Button href={'#playListUpdate/' + playlist._id} className="btn btn-primary editButton">Edit</Button>{' '}
          </div>
        ) : ''}
      </li>
    ))
    return (
      <div>
        <p className="userCreatedPlaylists">
          {playlists}
        </p>
        <Link to="/playlists" className="btn btn-secondary backButton">Back</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(PlayListsCreated)
```

I thought this code would do it

```
{(this.props.user._id === playlist.owner) ? (
          <div>
            <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.onPlaylistDelete} className="btn btn-secondary deleteButton">Delete</Button>{' '}
            <Button href={'#playListUpdate/' + playlist._id} className="btn btn-primary editButton">Edit</Button>{' '}
          </div>
        ) : ''}
```

But this is the output from the browser with the above code.

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `PlayListsCreated`.

▶ 23 stack frames were collapsed.

(anonymous function)
.../playListsCreated.js:29

  26 |   const { user } = this.props
  27 |   playListIndex(user)
  28 |     .then(res => {
> 29 |       this.setState({ playlists: res.data.playlists })
  30 |     })
  31 | }

View compiled
```

Please do not give me hints to the answer I just want the exact code that would do what I'm asking. I do not understand react classes that well and would not be able to figure it out with hints (unless you made it really obvious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
```

By

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
```